# Path traversal in REST style URLs?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability, rest, directory-traversal

Can path traversal vulnerabilities occur in REST style URLs?

For example: `https://x.com/filename/img.jpeg`

```
https://x.com/filename/../../../../../etc/passwd
```

Does this make sense ?

Comment: Is there a path behind the REST calls?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "REST style URLs". All URLs are just URLs. If you wanted to ask if REST services are vulnerable to path traversal attacks, here is the answer.

It depends on the implementation. In Java based frameworks like Apache CXF, Jersey, RESTeasy, Spring Boot etc. and in ASP.NET it is not possible, because first they search for code that corresponds to the URL. If no such code found, the return an error, often HTTP 404.

But if you implement REST service with scripts in a CGI manner and if you map URLs to file system paths, then yes, such implementation can be vulnerable to path traversal attacks.